# Python CSV: Grab all values in row with conditions for time values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

example for csv data with condition that I'm trying to get:

```
c1,c2,v1,v2,p1,p2,r1,a1,f1,f2,f3,Time_Stamp 

0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:00
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:01
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:02
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:03
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:04
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:05
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:06
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:07
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:08
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:09
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:10
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:11
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:12
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:13
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:14
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:15
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:16 
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:17
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:18
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:19
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:20
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:21
```

Codes for reading the csv:

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
import numpy as np
from datetime import date,time,datetime
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readcsv(x): #def function to read csv files based on code below*
    Data = pd.read_csv(x, parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    Data['Date'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.date #date column in DataFrame
    Data['Time'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.time #time column in DataFrame

    Data['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Time_Stamp'])
    print(Data[1:6])
    return Data

Data = readcsv('datafile.csv')#*

def getMask(start,end,Data):
    mask = (Data['Time_Stamp'] > start) & (Data['Time_Stamp'] <= end)
    return mask;

start = '2017-06-13 16:00:00'
end = '2017-06-13 16:40:00'
timerange = Data.loc[getMask(start, end, Data)] #* <----  using this Dataframe
#timeR.plot(x='Time_Stamp', y='AC_Input_Current', style='-', color='black')
```

What I'm trying to get is:

[for e.g.] After executing `pspike` ( code is below ) I'll get the following output:

```
13/06/2017 16:38:00
13/06/2017 16:38:01
13/06/2017 16:38:02
13/06/2017 16:38:03
13/06/2017 16:38:04
13/06/2017 16:38:05
13/06/2017 16:38:06
13/06/2017 16:38:07
13/06/2017 16:38:08
13/06/2017 16:38:09
13/06/2017 16:38:10
13/06/2017 16:38:11
13/06/2017 16:38:12
13/06/2017 16:38:13
13/06/2017 16:38:14
13/06/2017 16:38:15
13/06/2017 16:38:17
13/06/2017 16:38:18
13/06/2017 16:38:19
13/06/2017 16:38:20
13/06/2017 16:38:21
```

*Note that I'm using the dataframe `timerange` where it has every second of `Time` value from `16:00:00` to `16:40:00`, to get `pspike` where it does the skipping of rows if `c1` value is < 5.0

[ from output `print(pspike)` ]
**Condition**: if the printed row where `Time` value is `16:38:15`, and the following row's `Time` value is `16:38:17` ( where the next row's `Time` value skipped 1 second )...
Print the row that was skipped ( in this case, it's where the `Time` value is `16:38:16` )

```
pspike = (timerange.loc[timerange['AC_Input_Current'] <= 5.0])    
print(pspike)

with open('welding_data_by_selRange.csv','a', newline='') as duraweld:
    a = csv.writer(duraweld)
    data = [countIC2 ,countIC, Datetime]
    a.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Does it have to be a pandas solution?? What if it more than one second is *skipped* between consecutive rows?

Comment: If possible, in pandas, but I wouldn't mind seeing another method to go about it. As for what if it skipped more than 1 second, it doesn't matter, just need the ones that skipped 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

Following code will prints missing time stamps, no matter how many time stamps are missing, so it is more robust than previous solution.

```
for i in range(df.shape[0] - 1):
    row1 = df.iloc[i]
    row2 = df.iloc[i+1]
    skipped_ts = (row2[-1] - row1[-1]).seconds
    if  skipped_ts > 1:
    for ts in range(1,skipped_ts):
        print (row1[-1] + pd.Timedelta(ts * '1s'))
```

Comment: oh wow, it worked! I wasn't sure of the function of `df.shape` at first so I looked up on it, then tried your example, Thanks!

Comment: 'df.shape' is one of the most useful things when iterating/modifying or doing anything else for the entire df.

Comment: Is it possible to get the row that was skipped based on the condition? 
For e.g. _row1.values_ : `2017-06-13 16:00:04` and _row2.values_: `2017-06-13 16:00:06` , can i get the row where the it has the timestamp value of `2017-06-13 16:00:05`

Comment: is `2017-06-13 16:00:05` in your data set? from your question it seems that there are some missing time-stamps (`2017-06-13 16:00:05`). If time-stamps are ordered and one is missing, there is no value to get. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: `2017-06-13 16:00:05` is in the dataset ( timerange ). But the missing time are based on the conditions after I ran the code you provided.

Comment: If `2017-06-13 16:00:04`, `2017-06-13 16:00:05`, `2017-06-13 16:00:06` are all in the data set (as you said) and the data set is sorted based on time stamps (as it appears from the sample data you provided), then the condition (`if (row2[-1] - row1[-1]).seconds > 1:`) will not be true and the code will not print anything. If `2017-06-13 16:00:05` is not in the data set and you want to generate it or save it somewhere (e.g. if you want the missing time stamps to be printed instead of row1 and row2), then you can replace last two lines with `print (row1[-1] + pd.Timedelta('1s'))`.

Comment: If I misunderstood, please update your question with precise explanation of what exactly is the desired output.

Comment: I've edited the question based on what desired output that I actually need.

Answer (score 0):

**Non-Pandas solution**

From each row, extract the timestamp and the other info; turn the timestamp into a datetime.datetime object using a format string; subtract the current timestamp from the previous timestamp; test for elapsed time and process if applicable.

```
import datetime, io

#setup
s = '''0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:12
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:13
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:15
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:16
'''
#data is a file-like object
data = io.StringIO(s)

fmt = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
previous = None

for row in data:
    *info, timestamp = row.strip().split(',')
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, fmt)
    try:
        dt = timestamp-previous[0]
    except TypeError as e:
        previous = (timestamp, info)
        continue
    if dt.seconds > 1:
        print('!!!\tprevious:{}\n\tcurrent:{}'.format(previous,(timestamp, info)))
    previous = (timestamp, info)
```

It could be adapted for a csv.reader.

---

The timestamp is initially obtained from the last column in the row by splitting it. Then it is *made into* a datetime.datetime object so time differences can be easily calculated.

For a disk file open it and iterate over it...

```
with open(filepath) as data:
    for row in data:
        *info, timestamp = row.strip().split(',')
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, fmt)
        ....
```

Using a csv reader:

```
import csv
with open(filepath) as data:
    rows = csv.reader(data)
    for row in rows:
        *info, timestamp = row
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, fmt)
        ....
```

If you can read the whole file into a dataframe, you should be able to read it *into a  variable*.

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    data = f.read()

for row in data:
    *info, timestamp = row.strip().split(',')
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, fmt)
    ....
```

Comment: Before I proceed on trying it out, is the `timestamp` based on the column name or its just a variable/function?

Comment: I've tried the codes your provided but I encountered this error: _TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame_  . I believe i can't put it to string as the data I'm supposedly using has a huge amount of data.